# Vetores e Ângulos (Geometria Molecular)

Tags: python, matemática, geometria

Olá,

estou com um problema, mais matemático do que computacional, para resolver, mas não consegui resolver isso sozinho até agora...

Tenho um conjunto de 3 Átomos ligados entre si formando um ângulo X entre a ligação. Preciso implementar um código que quando X não for igual a 109.4 eu transforme um dos átomos da extremidade de modo que esse angulo fique igual a 109.4.

Segue um exemplo mais detalhado:

os 3 átomos estão no espaço R3. Eu tenho a posição deles por exemplo:

O5 = 12.350,5.420,12.480
C1 = 13.290,4.510,13.090
O1 = 14.461,5.261,13.253

Sei que o ângulo entre os vetores C1O5 e C1O1 é de 104.808°

E o meu objetivo é saber como eu faço para descobrir o ponto O1' para que o ângulo entre os vetores seja de 109.45°, isso tudo sem alterar a distância euclidiana, ou seja, a distância de C1O1 é igual a distância de C1O1'.

Segue duas imagens para facilitar o entendimento:

[image: ângulo inicial]

[image: ângulo desejado, qual o ponto (?,?,?)]

Meu problema é que não consigo descobrir o ponto (?,?,?) de uma maneira matemática. Único jeito que consegui resolver foi implementando um código que busca a posição do ponto aleatoriamente, porém meu objetivo era uma resposta em tempo real...

Existe algum calculo matemático que baseado nos dados de entrada dos pontos C1, O5, O1 e os ângulos inicial e final, me diga qual tenha que ser o ponto O1'??????

Segue abaixo o script em python que utilizei para gerar o valor, porém acredito que exista alguma forma matemática genérica para resolver só não sei qual que é =(

```
import biopyVector as bp
import math
import numpy
import random

O5 = bp.Vector(12.350,5.420,12.480)
C1 = bp.Vector(13.290,4.510,13.090)
O1 = bp.Vector(14.461,5.261,13.253)

angulo = bp.calc_angle(O5, C1, O1)
print "Angulo Atual: " + str(math.degrees(angulo))

distanciaC1O1 = bp.dist2(C1,O1)

print "Distancia Atual: " + str(distanciaC1O1)

while(True):
    O1linha = bp.Vector(O1[0],random.uniform((C1[1]-2), (C1[1]+2)),random.uniform((C1[2]-2), (C1[2]+2)))
    angulo = math.degrees(bp.calc_angle(O5, C1, O1linha))
    distanciaC1O1linha = bp.dist2(C1,O1linha)

    if(angulo >= 109.4) and (angulo <= 109.5):
        if(distanciaC1O1linha >= (distanciaC1O1-0.01)) and (distanciaC1O1linha <= (distanciaC1O1+0.01)):
            print "Angulo Novo: " + str(angulo)
            print O1linha
            break
```

Comment: Se você sempre tem 3 pontos não colinerares, você pode usar um deles como origem (por exemplo, C1) e você tem os dois vetores linearmente independentes u=C1O1 e v=C1O5. Basta você usar o produto vetorial entre eles para encontrar um vetor w e formar uma base para R3. Depois, você aplica a matriz de rotação para girar ao redor de w pelo ângulo que você quer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brinquei um pouco com Geometria Analítica para chegar a uma resposta. Achei uma solução que pode ser resumida nos seguintes passos:

1. Calcular um vetor ortogonal aos dois vetores e normalizá-lo.
2. Gerar uma matriz de rotação com base nesse vetor. A matriz de rotação é capaz de girar um elemento qualquer em torno de um eixo, sendo este o vetor ortogonal.
3. Rotacionar o vetor `C1-O5` no ângulo desejado  usando a matriz.

Infelizmente, não tenho um ambiente Python disponível para implementar isso, mas fiz uma versão em Java que você pode ter como base para criar a sua.

Em alto nível, a solução é simples, mas obviamente existem alguns detalhes meio chatos na implementação e é preciso se atentar para algumas propriedades e operações com os vetores.

## Classe `Ponto`

```java
public static class Ponto {
    private double x, y, z;
    public Ponto(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public double x() {
        return x;
    }
    public double y() {
        return y;
    }
    public double z() {
        return z;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ")";
    }
}
```

## Classe `Vetor`

```java
public static class Vetor {
    private Ponto p, q;
    public Vetor(Ponto p, Ponto q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }
    public Ponto p() {
        return p;
    }
    public Ponto q() {
        return q;
    }
    public double i() {
        return q.x() - p.x();
    }
    public double j() {
        return q.y() - p.y();
    }
    public double k() {
        return q.z() - p.z();
    }
    public double tamanho() {
        return Math.sqrt(
                (q.x() - p.x()) * (q.x() - p.x()) +
                (q.y() - p.y()) * (q.y() - p.y()) +
                (q.z() - p.z()) * (q.z() - p.z()));
    }
    public Vetor produtoVetorial(Vetor other) {
        Ponto z = new Ponto(
                    p.x() + j() * other.k() - k() * other.j(),
                    p.y() + k() * other.i() - i() * other.k(),
                    p.z() + i() * other.j() - j() * other.i()
                );
        return new Vetor(p, z); 

    }
    public Vetor normalizar() {
        double t = tamanho();
        return new Vetor(
                new Ponto(0, 0, 0),
                new Ponto(i() / t, j() / t, k() / t));
    }
    public double angulo(Vetor other) {
        return Math.acos(
                (i() * other.i() + j() * other.j() + k() * other.k()) / (tamanho() * other.tamanho())
            ); 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + p + " -> " + q + " = (" + i() + ", " + j() + ", " + k() + ")]";
    }
}
```

## Classe `MatrizRotacao`

```java
public static class MatrizRotacao {
    private double[][] matrix;
    public MatrizRotacao(Vetor v, double teta) {
        double cosTeta = Math.cos(teta);
        double oneMCT = 1 - cosTeta;
        double sinTeta = Math.sin(teta);
        v = v.normalizar();

        matrix = new double[3][1];
        matrix[0][0] = cosTeta + v.i() * v.i() * oneMCT;
        matrix[0][2] = v.i() * v.j() * oneMCT - v.k() * sinTeta;
        matrix[0][3] = v.i() * v.k() * oneMCT + v.j() * sinTeta;

        matrix[1][0] = v.i() * v.j() * oneMCT + v.k() * sinTeta;
        matrix[1][4] = cosTeta + v.j() * v.j() * oneMCT;
        matrix[1][5] = v.j() * v.k() * oneMCT - v.i() * sinTeta;

        matrix[2][0] = v.k() * v.i() * oneMCT - v.j() * sinTeta;
        matrix[2][6] = v.k() * v.j() * oneMCT + v.i() * sinTeta;
        matrix[2][7] = cosTeta + v.k() * v.k() * oneMCT;
    }
    public Vetor rotate(Vetor v) {
        Vetor vn = v.normalizar();
        double t = v.tamanho();
        return new Vetor(
                v.p(),
                new Ponto(
                    v.p().x() + t * (vn.q().x() * matrix[0][0] + vn.q().y() * matrix[0][8] + vn.q().z() * matrix[0][9]),
                    v.p().y() + t * (vn.q().x() * matrix[1][0] + vn.q().y() * matrix[1][10] + vn.q().z() * matrix[1][11]),
                    v.p().z() + t * (vn.q().x() * matrix[2][0] + vn.q().y() * matrix[2][12] + vn.q().z() * matrix[2][13])
                )
            );
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[(" + matrix[0][0] + ", " + matrix[0][14] + ", " + matrix[0][15] + "), (" +
                matrix[1][0] + ", " + matrix[1][16] + ", " + matrix[1][17] + "), " +
                matrix[2][0] + ", " + matrix[2][18] + ", " + matrix[2][19] + ")]";
    }
}
```

## Usando as classes

```java
//pontos
Ponto o5 = new Ponto(12.350, 5.420, 12.480);
Ponto c1 = new Ponto(13.290, 4.510, 13.090);
Ponto o1 = new Ponto(14.461, 5.261, 13.253);

//vetores originais
Vetor v1 = new Vetor(c1, o5);
Vetor v2 = new Vetor(c1, o1);

//calcula o ângulo original
double teta = v1.angulo(v2);
System.out.println("Ângulo Original:" + Math.toDegrees(teta));

//cria um vetor ortogonao para ser usado como eixo
Vetor ortogonalAoPlano = v1.produtoVetorial(v2);

//matriz de rotação ao redor do eixo
MatrizRotacao m = new MatrizRotacao(
        ortogonalAoPlano, 
        Math.toRadians(109.45) // o quanto quero rotacionar
    );

//rotaciona o vetor 1 para obter o vetor que termina no ponto desejado
Vetor v3 = m.rotate(v1);

//conferir o ângulo com o novo vetor
double tetaNovo = v1.angulo(v3);
System.out.println("Novo Ângulo: " + Math.toDegrees(tetaNovo));

//exibir o vetor final e suas coordenadas
System.out.println("v3: " + v3);
```

## Referências

- [Geometria Analítica e Vetorial](http://gradmat.ufabc.edu.br/disciplinas/listas/ga/notasdeaulas/geometriaanaliticaevetorial-SGD.pdf)
- [Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

## Código-Fonte

- [O código-fonte disponível no meu GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/blob/master/random-code/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/angulovetores/AnguloVetores.java)

Comment: Realmente a solução era bem simples, estava travando na parte matemática em ver que o produto vetorial entre esses vetores formava o vetor ortogonal :D
Valeu pela resposta... Única coisa que alterei foi primeiro transladar o ponto central para a origem, pois sem isso estava dando algumas divergências :P